# WPF: Basic question about Dependency Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, xaml, dependency-properties

I have the following Xaml in a `Window` (`ArtistInfo`):

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist.Name}"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

And this is the code-behind for the same window (*code simplified for question's sake*):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ArtistProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("Artist", typeof(Artist), typeof(ArtistInfo));

Artist Artist {
    get {
        return (Artist)GetValue(ArtistProperty);
    }
    set {
        SetValue(ArtistProperty, value);
    }
}

public ArtistInfo() {
    InitializeComponent();
}
public ArtistInfo(int artistID) {
    InitializeComponent();
    Artist = GetArtist(artistID);
}
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is data binding to a Dependency Property, so that when `Artist` is populated (in the constructor), the `TextBlock` gets filled with the Artist's name.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ...>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist.Name}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 5):

The only thing I didn't see was you updating the Binding source for the TextBlock.  First add a name to the TextBlock

```
<TextBlock Name="m_tb" ... />
```

Then update the DataContext value in the constructor

```
public ArtistInfo() {
 ...
 m_tb.DataContext = this;
}
```

**EDIT** OP mentioned that there may be more than one TextBlock or child element.

In that case I would do the above trick for the closest parent object to all of the values.  In this case the Grid control.  The DataContext property will be inherited so to speak by all of the inner children.

Comment: and if I have other textblocks (such as artist surname, age ...), do i have to set the DataContext of all those TextBlocks ?

Comment: @Dreas, in that case you should pick a parent element and set the DataContext there. It will be "inherited" by child elements

Comment: The DataContext is searched in all your Visual Tree, so if you want all your TextBlocks to have the same DataContext, set the DataContext at the Grid or Window level.

Comment: @Slashene, yup that's exactly what I did infact.